# Есть ли методы позволяющие добиться корректного излома штриха в необходимой точке (узле) ломаной?

Tags: google-maps-api

При использовании библиотеки drawing google maps пытаюсь построить пунктирную ломаную линию. Для этого создаю ее path  и использую в соответствии с документацией. При этом не происходит излома или обрезания линии в необходимых точках (узлах) линии.

Вот здесь пример моего кода (нужно зайти и построить ломаную):
[`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nX8U8/161/)

В результате при построении штриховой ломаной на карте я получаю (см. прикрепленный рисунок ниже):
                                      [image: Илюстрация ошибки]

Есть ли методы позволяющие добиться корректного излома штриха в необходимой точке (узле) ломаной?